# Koa api pre processing manipulating query

Tags: neo4j, koa

I am using koa api for neo4j. I was creating a cypher query in preprocessing life cycle because i want to parametrized labels so i achieved this and was working fine. but from yesterday all api call in which queries is prepared in preprocess phase is giving error. 
This was the query:

```
app.defineAPI({
    allowedRoles: ['admin', 'user'],
    method: 'POST',
    route: '/v0.3/imm/createNode',
    preProcess: function (params, ctx) {
        params.uid = ctx.user.id;
        var props = JSON.stringify(params.props);
        props = props.replace(/"(\w+)"\s*:/g, '$1:');
        params.cypher = ' MATCH(u:user)-[r1:HAS_ACCESS_TO {permission:"full"}]-(c:organizationCatalog)';
        params.cypher += ' WHERE ID(u)=toInt(' + ctx.user.id + ')';
        params.cypher += ' CREATE (c)-[r2:CONTAINS]->(e:entity:' + params.props.type + ' ' + props + '), (s:state:' + params.props.type + 'State ' + props + '),(e)-[r3:HAS_STATE {from:timestamp(), to:9223372036854775807, current:true, modifiedBy:"mos"}]->(s)';
        params.cypher += ' SET s.dateCreated = timestamp(), e.dateCreated = timestamp()';
        params.cypher += ' RETURN e, s, r3';
        return params;
    }
});
```

This is i am getting error:

```
 ConflictError: error while executing Cypher: Neo4jError: Invalid input 'h': expected '*' or '/' (line 1, column 2 (offset: 1))
"/home/awais/ocwork/n4nite-api/ MATCH(u:user)-[r1:HAS_ACCESS_TO {permission:"full"}]->(c:organizationCatalog) WHERE ID(u)=toInt(3) CREATE (c)-[r2:CONTAINS]->(e:entity:dataAttribute {name:"dataAttribute",type:"dataAttribute",description:""}), (s:state:dataAttributeState {name:"dataAttribute",type:"dataAttribute",description:""}),(e)-[r3:HAS_STATE {from:timestamp(), to:9223372036854775807, current:true, modifiedBy:"mos"}]->(s) SET s.dateCreated = timestamp(), e.dateCreated = timestamp() RETURN e, s, r3"
  ^
```

It is concatenating path(/home/awais/ocwork/n4nite-api/) to my query, i dont have idea why its happening now Please help me.

Thanks